# programatically add images to canvas in fabricJS

Tags: fabricjs

I have an image to be added to a fabricJS canvas. The user will specify the number on times the same image should be added on the canvas.

When I loop through the number of times the user entered and use fabric.Image.fromURL to add, it gets added just once and only to the last location.

EDIT:

```
Here is the jsfiddle on what I am trying to do
http://jsfiddle.net/apsixion/9g0Lfydw/3/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I solved it today..
Moved the code to draw the image to a different function outside and called the function in a look. May not be the most optimal solution, but works for me.

```
// create a wrapper around native canvas element (with id="c")
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c', {
    selection: false
});

function drawRectangles(number) {

    i = 0;
    var pic =
        "http://depts.washington.edu/hplab/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/smiley-e1415084033498.jpeg";
    for (var i = 0; i < number; i++) {
        var rect = new fabric.Rect({
            left: 5 + i * 160,
            top: 10,
            width: 150,
            height: 150,
            lockRotation: true,
            lockMovementX: false,
            lockMovementY: false
        });
        canvas.add(rect);
    }
    for (var k = 0; k < number; k++) {
        drawStars(k);
    }
}

function drawStars(k) {
    var picStars =
        "http://reviews.babymonitorsdirect.co.uk/images/5-stars.jpg";

    fabric.Image.fromURL(picStars, function (img2) {

        img2.set({
            lockRotation: true,
            lockMovementX: true,
            lockMovementY: true,
            left: 5 + k * 160,
            top: 10,
            width: 50,
            height: 50,
            lockScalingX: true,
            lockScalingY: true,
            selectable: true,
            hasControls: false
        });
        canvas.add(img2);

    });

}
drawRectangles(5);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/apsixion/z6dq0dp9/2/